# Greens Function for poisson equation in cartesian along boundary

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics, boundary-value-problem, greens-function

I am tryng to solve
$$\nabla ^2 \phi = -\rho(\vec x)$$
Where $\phi(0) =0$ and $\phi(L)=\phi_0$ and $\rho$ is an arbitrary functionAccording to [wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GreensFunctionPoissonsEquation.html) we can write G in terms of spherical harmonics, which then leaves me wondering how I can have the boundary conditions met from
$$\phi = \int G\rho d^3x$$
I know I can add a solution to laplaces equation (maybe $\phi = \phi_0 x/L$) but other that that I am not sure.

The rationale is that I have an electrostatics problem of an arbitrary charge distribution in between two conducting plates, one at 0V and the other at Vo, which reduced to this BVP.

Comment: Are you aware of the [method of image charges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_image_charges)?

Comment: Yes.  But I have an arbitrary charge distribution and am asked to find the charge on each plate in terms of the moments of the charge distribution, so I need phi to solve for the surface charge